# JDA - VoiceChannel#getMembers() isn't returning voice users

Tags: java, discord-jda

I want to iterate through my discord's voices channels and get their members.
But my code (below) isn't working as expected.

```
for (VoiceChannel voiceChannel : event.getJDA().getGuildById(Config.guildId).getVoiceChannelCache()) {
   System.out.println("-> " + voiceChannel.getName() + " -->> " + voiceChannel.getMembers().size());
}
```

However I put it after a ReadyEvent, so I don't know why it isn't working

Comment: (It returns 0 for every voice channels)

Comment: Did you enable `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent?

Comment: Yes it's enabled

Comment: "isn't working as expected." What happens? What do you expect?

Comment: Note that `getVoiceChannelCache()` just gets the cached voice channels. This might not include all voice channels (depending on the set cache flags).

Comment: Oh, ok then, how can I enable this flag ?